# AngularJS-Ionic : create a swipeable horizonatlview which will update vertical view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a UI for Android and iOS using angularjs and ionic. View is as below:
[image]

**Explanation**: In this view I want to have a horizontal strip (1 to 8 date displayed currently but it will be swipeable from day 1 of the month to last day of month) containing dates. This strip will be swipeable left and right. Each day will have some data which will be displayed in vertical list view. When user will swipe left or right on horizontal strip at the same time vertical data will update. Vertical list view will show data only of dates displayed in horizontal strip.

I am not sure how I can do it. Any pointer e.g. library/sample code etc will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: look into hammer.js for swipe detection

Comment: you can try this http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would recommend `swiper` , i used it before and i find it simple and easy to work with : http://idangero.us/swiper/ , http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

documentation : http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

> Swiper is also a default slider component in Ionic Framework

quick overview :

you can configure it to display `x` slides at a time, and the one in the middle will always have the `swiper-slide-active` class, you have an event `slideChange` that's fired when the `swiper-slide-active` is changed, you can put in that whatever function you want ( maybe an ajax one to fetch the day's data ) it's just fired a bit too early so you need to wrap it in `setTimeout` of `1ms`

i made a basic example according to you layout and here's a fiddle that you can play with and change it to your needs :

https://jsfiddle.net/o9u0qenk/15/ ( updated for the weeks )
https://jsfiddle.net/o9u0qenk/22/ ( updated for real time )

**EDIT**

to display the data in a range of 7 days, `centeredSlides: true` is removed so `swiper-slide-active` becomes the first slide on the left, so that's your `startDate`, add 6 to get the `endDate`

**Edit 2**

for tracking the days in real time, you can use the event `sliderMove` to detect whether the slider is moving and do some stuff while it does, and you can store the `offsetLeft` of each slide in an `Array` and loop through it when the user is swiping and comparing the values with the current `offset` of the swiper, then `break` when match not to continue through the `loop`

edited snippet :

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');
 
var currenOffset; // swiper's offset
var childOffset; // slide's offset
 
var startIndex; 
var endIndex;
 
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide');
var slidesOffsets = [];
  
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 7,
  spaceBetween: 10,      
  on: {
    init: function () {
      setTimeout(function(){
        var startDay = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide-active')[0].innerHTML;
        var endDay = parseInt(startDay) + 6 ;            
        content.innerHTML = '<div> Showing data for days ' + startDay + ' to ' + endDay + '</div>';
      }, 1);
    }
  }
});
 
swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var startDay = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide-active')[0].innerHTML;
    var endDay = parseInt(startDay) + 6 ;
    content.innerHTML = '<div> Showing data for days ' + startDay + ' to ' + endDay + '</div>';
  }, 1);
});


for(var i =0; i < slides.length; i++){
  slidesOffsets.push((slides[i].offsetLeft * -1) + 10);
}
 
swiper.on('sliderMove', function(e){
  currentOffset = this.translate;
  
  for(var i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
    if( slidesOffsets[i] <= currentOffset){    
      startIndex = i ;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  endIndex = startIndex + 6;
  content.innerHTML = '<div> Showing data for days ' + startIndex + ' to ' + endIndex +  '</div>';  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#content{
  width: 100%;
 height: calc(100% - 80px);  
}
#content div{   
  margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">10</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">11</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">12</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">13</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">14</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">15</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">16</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">17</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">18</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">19</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">20</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">21</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">22</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">23</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">24</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">25</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">26</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">27</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">28</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">29</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">30</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
 
 <div id="content">

 </div>
```

i hope this helps and good luck.

**Final Expected outcome** : https://jsfiddle.net/o9u0qenk/40/

Comment: your example is showing data of only one selected date but in my case there will not be any selected date but there will be 7 displayed dates and corresponding to those dates I want to show data in vertical scroll view.

Comment: oh, sorry for the misunderstanding , i just edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Almost there. Can you use this ( https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb92ca7f ) json and update data in vertical view at real time?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean in real time, like when the user is scrolling ?

Comment: Yes when user is scrolling

Comment: i updated my answer for the real time part, i'm pretty sure you can play around with the `json` to display it in your `html` as this will get off topic because the question wasn't about any `json` or data integration :)  , and honestly i'm not sure what to do with that `json`  as i don't know what's the end goal,  i hope this will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: i looked at the `json` again and i can't figure out what to display in the vertical part because there's only dates, if you can provide more details on what you want to accomplish or where are you struggling exactly i would be glad to answer you in another question or in the chat.

Comment: I want to display time key’s value in vertical list. As you can see if date from 1 to 7 is displayed then corresponding time will be displayed in vertical view and if user swipe to change date then vertical view also be updated and will display time of shown dates.

Comment: I want to accept your answer so please update it as per last comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167589/discussion-between-taki-and-vicjordan).